# How compare two txt file with python?

Tags: python

I want to find users who don't follow me on Instagram
I have two txt file

**iamfollowing.txt**
jhon
mike
dennis
pluto44
hunter34

**floowingme.txt**
dennis
pluto44

i want this output

dontfollowback.txt
jhon
mike
hunter34

Comment: Show the code you have. People wiil be glad to help you if you show your efforts until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('iamfollowing.txt', 'r') as f:
    iamfollowing = [name.strip() for name in f.readlines()]

with open('followingme.txt', 'r') as f:
    followingme = [name.strip() for name in f.readlines()]

notfollowing = [name for name in iamfollowing if name not in followingme]

print(notfollowing)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
with open('iamfollowing.txt', 'r') as ff:
    iamfollowing = ff.readlines()

with open('floowingme.txt', 'r') as fm:
    followingme = fm.readlines()

not_following_me = [p for p in iamfollowing if p not in followingme]
```

Comment: you use 2 time the same variable name "iamfollowing"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudocode for that (Its just to state planning like flowcharts)-

```
file1 = open('iamfollowing.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('floowingme.txt', 'r')

list_file1 = []
for line in file1:
    list_file1.extend([x for x in line.split()])

lst = []
for line in file2:
    for word in list(line.split()):
        if word not in list_file1:
            lst.append(word)

print(lst)
```